# Multivariate test in R

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to run a multivariate model where I have 3 dvs and no iv in r using the lm function

I have this sas code:

```
    proc glm; 
    model a b c = / nouni; 
    repeated shoe / mean nouni; 
    run;
```

I am trying to replicate this in r and I have been having a lot of troubles. I specified the model this way: mod <- lm(cbind(a, b, c) ~ 1, data = track_wi), and then used tried to use the Manova function in the "car" package, for example: Manova(mod). The problem is the output, the df r is outputting seem wrong. I have 6 participants and 3 variables, so df denominator should be 4, and df numerator should be 2. But R is outputting 3 for both df numerator and df denominator

below is a sample data

```
track <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                     a = c(20, 12, 18, 16, 21, 15),
                     b = c(18, 14, 19, 13, 19, 15),
                     c = c(10, 8, 14, 10, 15, 11))
```

This is my sas's output that I am trying to replicate in r: [sas's output using proc glm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3z1j.png)

Comment: Your SAS model has a within-subjects factor `shoe` that isn't accounted for in your R model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the manova function, this will give you an output similar to what you would get from the proc glm procedure in SAS.

```
    #Manova
library(car)
track <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                     a = c(20, 12, 18, 16, 21, 15),
                     b = c(18, 14, 19, 13, 19, 15),
                     c = c(10, 8, 14, 10, 15, 11))

mod <- manova(cbind(a, b, c) ~ 1, data = track)
summary(mod)
```

Or if you're looking to specifically extract the degrees of freedom from the model, you can do it as follows:

```
    # Extrae los grados de libertad
df_residual <- mod$stats$Residual[1]
```

residuales
df_total <- mod$stats$Totals[1]
df_residual
df_total

Comment: Hi Cesar, welcome to SO! Thank you for providing an answer. However, [all questions and answers on SO must be in English](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). If you're able, please feel free to [edit] your answer and translate to English. FYI, you might also consider contributing to [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Thank you Cesar. I have tried that and this is my output                                                  
> mod <- manova(cbind(a, b, c) ~ 1, data = track_wi)                                               
> summary (mod)
          Df Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
Residuals  5                                     
>

Comment: Please also translate the comments in the codeblocks. Thanks